# SwiftMailer Connection could not be established with host

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer

I am getting an unexpected problem with emails being sent from my site. It had been working fine for some time and all of a sudden seems to have stopped for no apparent reason.

> [Swift_TransportException] exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host [Connection timed out #110]' in vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:265

In my web.php

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'transport' => [
        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
        'host' => 'mail.website.com',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'port' => '587',
        'encryption' => 'tls',
        ],
```

What could have happened for this to stop working and how should I be fixing it?

I am using google apps for my emails, but I have always used this config where I connect to my mail server. I'm not sure why it suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same thing thing happened to me in yii , couple of days ago.Solved it by changing the port.

Try,

```
'port' => 26,
```

Comment: This worked for me, I have no idea why it stopped but pleased it started working.

Answer (score 0):

it's looking for the server mail.website.com but isn't able to resolve it.
use this domain `smtp.gmail.com` and port `25 or 465`.

```
if (!$this->_stream = fsockopen($host, $this->_params['port'], $errno, $errstr, $timeout))
{
  throw new Swift_TransportException(
    'Connection could not be established with host ' . $this->_params['host'] .
    ' [' . $errstr . ' #' . $errno . ']'
    );
}
```

So you either need to input a valid smtp server or wrap the send() line in a try/catch to catch the exception and either log it somewhere or ignore it.
Please checkif the port you use is really the port used by your mail server.