# Email sent from localhost but not sent after hosting?

Tags: php, smtp, yii2

I am using yii2 MVC framework. I have created an email application, it works fine in localhost but it gives an Connection Timed Out  exception after the code is online I used ssl and tls both for encrytpion and I couldnt find any genuine solutions please help

**My config file code is:**

```
'mailer' => [
  'class'            => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',                   
  'useFileTransport' => false,
  'transport'        => [
    'class'      => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
    'host'       => 'smtp.gmail.com', 
    'username'   => 'email@gmail.com',
    'password'   => 'password',
    'port'       => '587',
    'encryption' => 'tls',
  ],
]
```

**Message sending code:**

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                ->setFrom($from)
                ->setTo($to)
                ->setSubject('Hello')
                ->setTextBody('Hello')
                ->send();
```

**Error:**

```
Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]
```

Comment: Maybe this helps you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34299862/swiftmailer-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host And this one as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420937/uncaught-exception-swift-transportexception-with-message-connection-could-not?rq=1

Comment: its still not working

Answer (score 0):

You should try Replacing your host:

`smtp.gmail.com`

with

`173.194.65.108` or `gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com`

If it still doesn't work then try changing your port to `25` or `465`

Comment: I contacted to my service provider and hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In your config file:

- Change `port` to *465* and `encryption` to *ssl*.
- In your gmail account settings check that you have **IMAP** enabled.

**Info about gmail settings:**

[1] https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en&ref_topic=1354753

[2] https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

remove from your config.yml `spool:     { type: memory }`

Then you will be to add try catch like this

```
try{
        $mailer = $this->getMailer();
        $response = $this->getMailer()->send($message);
    }catch(\Swift_TransportException $e){
        $response = $e->getMessage() ;
    }
```

Or Else

try following port number

```
'port' => 26
```

or

```
'port' => 465.
```